# The number of helpful flags has disappeared

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

I have noticed today that the number of helpful flags in a user's profile is no longer shown. I can see it on my own profile, but I can't see it on other user's profiles.

[image]

This was the only place this information was available. It's not available via API or on any other page in the user activity tab.

Comment: On your own profile or other people's? My observation is I can see the number on my own profile and not on other people's.

Comment: I've reproduced this on Meta SE and Meta SO (which is where builds go first, before going to the main sites) so I assume this is a recent build that introduced a bug that's not rolled out fully yet. **Update**: I've reproduced this on main SO now. I can't see Dharman's helpful flag count.

Comment: @Spevacus ugh. I will keep an eye on it - it is bad enough that I forget how to get to flags from time to time, now this. Really hope this is not intentional

Comment: Repro'd for others' profiles too

Comment: Might be [a regression](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/249988/786798), btw

Comment: Somewhat weirdly, it's there for me as a mod, but not in incognito. Both instances running rev. 2022.1.5.41084. Not sure if this is intentional though. Also checked with a low-rep user, where I can see flag counts on the account itself, but no other accounts. I really, really hope this doesn't mean what the evidence indicates (that flag counts are hidden from the public), but I genuinely wouldn't be surprised if SE randomly got that idea while updating profiles. They've already hidden lots of other non-critical information from the public, why not flags next?

Comment: @Spevacus Who needs to know Dharman's exact helpful flag count?  The answer is just "Yes".  And yeah, I do hope this isn't intentional, as there are other uses for flag counts aside from amazed goggling, although the profile *is* a place for showing off your numbers and efforts.  What better to show off than your curation metrics?

Comment: @Zoe maybe it's a secret ploy to get people to nominate in mod elections - I guess nomination posts are now the easiest way (short of actually becoming one) to find that stat for other users :)

Comment: @bad_coder NP, my first hunch was to go to my profile too, Dharman clarified soon after that. I wouldn't be surprised if the UI team actually ripped out the stat from user profiles as well. Really hope it is a regression

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure that this is a regression, I think we can more expect a change in policy sometime this year and these kind of changes are a preparation for it. You're not supposed to look at those statistics anymore, they just haven't explained why not yet.

Comment: Perhaps we should ask on Meta SE? It's been 2 weeks already. This is worrying.

Comment: Also reported on MSE: [Where did the "helpful flags" go?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/375422/289905).

Comment: [Prior Meta.SE discussion on whether this info should be public or private](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/249981/377214). Do note that at the time, it was private; it wasn't made public until later that year.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The number of helpful flags was placed behind a conditional that only showed it if you were viewing your own profile and/or are a moderator. For what it's worth, this was unintentional. There were many nested conditionals in the Activity view and the display of this specific stat was lost in the refactor shuffle.

We've shipped out a fix to this, so helpful flags are visible to everyone once again. Thanks for reporting the bug!

Answer (score 43):

I can only assume this was intentional, so I have to argue that it should be put back, on every site.

Most of the time the count provides just a little bit of insight to what users are doing, to see if they're active in moderating the site. For some users (namely association bonus users) this may be their only type of activity on the site, while some high rep users may never participate in flagging at all.

But there's one really important role it plays. Helpful flag count is really important during a moderator election. It shows how much effort each user puts into successfully moderating the site, and even other sites — every helpful flag should count for something. (It also shows how many fewer flags the other moderators would have to handle if the user is elected and can only cast binding flags!) While this is something that could be revealed during one of the election phases (and someone would of course have to spend the time doing so), that won't be enough. This information should be available before the election even starts, so that people can judge if they're casting enough helpful flags or not compared to other users to even be a good choice for moderator.

Comment: *I can only assume this was intentional...* Yeah. Along the same lines of argument as the removal of the "Last seen" and "consecutive days" metrics. Probably considered a mixture of "privacy issue" and "vanity metric". We should have it back!